# Can I subclass a DOM-class?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was wondering if I can create a subclass of HTMLDivElement. Like this.

```
MyDivElement.prototype.pickColor = function()
{
    return this.picked;
}
function MyDivElement()
{
    this = new HTMLDivElement();
    this.picked = 'unknowd';
}
alert(this.picked); // print: 'unkowd'
```

Is (something like) this possible?
If not, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: An interesting and worthy question. Welcome to Stackoverflow! Be sure to [read the FAQ etc](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916728/overwrite-the-htmlnode-interface). basically no.

Comment: @Raynos Could you look at my answer? I think it answers the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new HTMLDivElement();` throws a TypError `"Illegal constructor"` in Chrome - so it's not possible.

Update: I've tested in other current browsers, and they throw various types of errors - but they all throw.

---

<s>Actually, this would work:</s>

```
function MyDivElement() {
    this.picked = 'unknowd';
}

MyDivElement.prototype = document.createElement('div');

var mydiv = new MyDivElement();
```

But I'm not sure how you could use this pattern...

Comment: That kind of code just does [not work](http://jsfiddle.net/hLgJ4/6/). Besides you've got a single div element as the prototype. Event if it did work how do you make two new div elements? There both pointing to the same `<div>`

Comment: @Raynos It actually works in Firefox 4 `:)`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/hLgJ4/8/

Comment: @Raynos Yes, you're right. It's useless since you cannot have multiple instances at the same time...

Comment: but it does not work in chrome so it's _useless_ ! Let's not go back to the days of having firefox or IE only code ;)

Answer (score 6):

In browsers where `__proto__` is exposed and mutable you can sub class DOM elements. It looks like this:

```
function CustomEl () {
    var el = document.createElement('div')
    el.__proto__ = CustomEl.prototype
    return el
}
CustomEl.prototype.__proto__ = HTMLDivElement.prototype
```

I also played with it in more detail on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9T7T/1/). Unfortunately though IE and Opera don't allow `__proto__` access and have no plans to in the future as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers, you can extend the prototype, in others, no.  I'll let you guess the ones where you can't. :-)  That's not really the same as extending a DOM element, but it does let you do a certain subset of the things for which you might want that facility. The thing is, DOM elements aren't really JavaScript entities; they're only simulacrums provided by the runtime system.  (Maybe someday all the jsdom work will actually come to fruition.)

Well ok I'll tell you about the problematic browsers: IE doesn't like that at all. However others do.  If you've ever looked at the Prototype library, you'll come across a manifestation of that fact all the time via nasty irritating IE-only bugs when you forget to Prototype-ize a DOM element reference.

(IE9 may be different, but I sort-of doubt it.)

This is the kind of thing that's dirt simple to test over at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: The W3C DOM specifications are written to be language neutral. They do not assume or enforce any particular programming environment, only that the DOM objects in that environment provide the interfaces specified. Therefore it is illogical to say that failure to provide ECMAScript-style prototype inheritance for DOM objects is a bug. It isn't.

Comment: Did I say it was a bug?  Let's see ... no, I didn't. The word "bug" directed at browsers appears nowhere in my answer. I said that IE is "problematic" because, if you're trying to add methods to a DOM element prototype, it simply **is** problematic - but that's not to say it's a "bug" in the browser. It's just an impediment to getting what you want :-)

Comment: Oh, and by "IE-only bugs", I didn't mean that the **browser** is buggy, I meant that errant Prototype code can fall foul of the browser differences if you're not careful. It's a code bug, not a browser bug, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experimenting with this a little bit.  A big difficulty is that you need the context of a document to create an element.  You can go with `window.document` as a default, but that's boring.

Here's the POC I'm working on:

```
function CustomNode(type, parent) { 
    if (type instanceof Node) {
        // Decorate a preexisting node appropriately if called that way.
        if (arguments.length === 2 && type.ownerDocument !== parent) {
            // Import the node if it's not owned by the requested document.
            type = parent.importNode(type, true);
        }
        return Object.assign(type, this.__proto__);
    }
    //Normal flow, e.g., new CustomNode("div");
    var d = document;
    if (parent) {
        // Alt document flow, e.g., new CustomNode("div", xmlDoc);
        if (parent.nodeType === 9) {
            d = parent;
        } else {
            // Support for new CustomNode("div", parentElement);
            //  This doesn't append the element, just makes sure 
            //  the documents match
            d = parent.ownerDocument;
        }
    }
    var inst;
    // Creation flags
    if (type[0] === '#') { //text
        inst = d.createTextNode(type.substr(1));
    } else if (type[0] === '?') { //Processing instruction
        type = type.substr(1).split(' ');
        inst = d.createProcessingInstruction(type.shift(), type.join(' '));
    } else if (type[0] === '[') { // CDATA
        inst = d.createCDATASection(type.substr(1));
    } else if (type[0] === '/') { // Comment
        inst = d.createComment(type.substr(1));
    } else { //Everything else gets an element.
        inst = d.createElement(type);
    }
    // DE-COR-ATE
    Object.assign(inst, this.__proto__);
    return inst;
}
// Decorator for customized NodeLists; probably inefficient.  Decorates
//   contents with CustomNode
function CustomNodeList(list) {
    var Self = this.constructor,
        CNode = this.Node;
    return Object.assign([].map.call(list, function (node) {
        return new CNode(node);
    }), this.__proto__);
}
CustomNodeList.prototype = {
    // so we know how to wrap...
    Node: CustomNode,
    text: function () {
        return this[0].textContent;
    }
};


CustomNode.prototype = {
    // So we know how to decorate NodeLists
    NodeList: CustomNodeList,
    // So we know how to decorate Nodes
    Node: CustomNode,
    // Easy make-and-attach
    new: function (type, attach) {
        var CNode = this.Node;
        var ret = new CNode(type, this.ownerDocument);
        if (attach) {
            this.appendChild(ret);
        }
        return ret;
    },
    // NodeLists with ES5 iterators!
    find: function () {
        var CNodeList = this.NodeList;
        return new CNodeList(this.querySelectorAll.apply(this, arguments));
    },
    kids: function () {
        var CNodeList = this.NodeList;
        return new CNodeList(this.childNodes);
    }
};
```

Mind, this is likely a bad idea: everything in the same scope of these functions (including the elements themselves) will *never* get garbage collected, as the GC in most browsers is dead-stupid when it comes to elements referencing objects. I'll never use it for production for that reason alone: it's a straight-up memory leak.